# Rounded boxes around text

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I have following problem. I want to create rounded boxes around my text, so far I have:

```
\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]\node[anchor=north west, draw,rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=1.6pt, minimum size=5.5mm, text height=3.6mm, fill=#2,#2,text=white](char){#1};\phantom{#1};%}
```

and it gives me:

[image]

Which is quite good, but I would also like to extend boxes (I think it's written too tight) like 2mm each side. Ideas?

Comment: you can use `inner xsep = 2mm`

Answer (score 7):

With `tcolorbox` ([documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\mybox}[1][red]{on line,
    colback=#1, colframe=#1, boxsep=0pt, boxrule=0pt, size=small, arc=1mm}
\begin{document}
\mybox{This is some} \mybox[blue!30]{text with} \mybox[green!70]{rounded corners}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With `fancybox` ([documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancybox)):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\begin{document}

\ovalbox{one box}

\Ovalbox{another box}

\end{document}
```

[image: ovalbox]

---

**Remark on using *fancybox* and *minted***

From the [minted documentation](https://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf):

> Weird things happen when I use the fancybox package. fancybox
> conflicts with fancyvrb, which minted uses internally. When using
> fancybox, **make sure that it is loaded before minted**.