# Writing a good formation with latex

Tags: math-mode, pdf

How to write it? This problem bug me for a long time. Until now, I still don't know...
[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please, add the code for your first attempts.

Comment: As others have mentions this is not a `please do this for me` service. We provide answers to concrete questions. You might want to have a look at `tikz`

Comment: The first three google results: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34088/82917, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66154/82917, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/426973/82917

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Sorry,  I will keep what you say in mymind

Comment: I am not a native english speaker. I do not know how to express my problem in a better way.

Comment: \newtheorem{problem}{\large \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{Problem}}} This is my attempt. I use theorem to create a environment(?) But the outcome isn't what I want.

Comment: @meteor, maybe this is what you want: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/325122/220875, have a look et the `enumitem`-package. There is a lot you can do with description lists.

Comment: @campa For my humble opinion it is a duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127602/colored-box-around-enumerate-labels if we change in `arabic` numbers.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a very first start with lots of room for improvement. At least now you can play with different settings for widths and colors.

Here's the code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{%
    \hspace{\labelsep}%
    \colorbox{yellow}{\textbf{#1}}%
    \par
}

\newlist{mydescription}{description}{1}

\setlist[mydescription]{
  topsep=2ex,
  partopsep=2ex,
  itemsep=1ex,
  font=\bfseries\color{blue},
  labelwidth=3em,
  labelsep*=2em,
  leftmargin =!,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mydescription}
  \item[G1.] The first item
  \item[G2.] The second item

  A longish explanation every true mathematician would deem completely unnecessary …
  \item[G3.] The third item etc …
\end{mydescription}

\end{document}
```

Here's the output:

[image: Colored Description Labels]